# How do I access an IBM Cloud Object Storage instance to use in Watson Studio?

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, cloud-object-storage

I am working on a course and the project had me create an account in IBM Cloud (all are in the Lite/Free account), then create an instance of IBM Watson Studio, then try to create a new, empty project. When I created the project and added the storage, I was taken back to Watson but there was no instance of a project.

I tried to create another one, but now it says that I already have an instance of the Cloud Object Storage and can't create a new one (Message says: Create Service, You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan.). However, there is no instance listed for the COS in the Resource List (though it shows the Watson instance), and I don't get an option to select an existing COS, only to add a new one.

I have searched the help in IBM, Googled for help, logged out and back in, closed the tabs, cleared my cache, checked other answers in Stack Overflow, and can find no help to create a project, access, delete, or do anything with the instance of the COS. I tried entering the administrator and manager settings in the account for Watson Studio and COS, but that didn't help either.

Is there any way that I can correct this so I can move on in the project? I tried to add screen shots, but I'm not allowed to. Thanks for any help!

Comment: No way to solve, I think. I ended up making a new account, had same problem in free/lite :-(

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling. Were you able to make the project in the new account?

Comment: Yes, for now it's ok

Comment: Thanks again, I appreciate it!

Comment: I finally figured it out! In Watson Studio in the menu, click on Administration, then click Storage Delegation. Then click the buttons to enable projects and catalogs. Try to create your project and it should automatically have your object storage available.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out! In Watson Studio in the menu, click on Administration, then click Storage Delegation. Then click the buttons to enable projects and catalogs. Try to create your project and it should automatically have your object storage available.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see your COS instances at https://cloud.ibm.com/resources under the "Storage" section.
All your Watson instances will under "Services"

Another check you'll need to make is the Account. At the top right corner, make sure you're working in the same account that you initially created the Object Storage instance.

Comment: That was the problem, the instance didn't show up in the resource list. But I figured it out, by going to Administration in Watson Studio, and selecting Storage Delegation, I needed to switch the buttons so the instance was accessible by projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the sam issue and that work for me is that click the "Refresh" button under the 1. Storage

[Like this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiIjC.png)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I have added screenshots to clarify what I mean